# Custom slider – jQuery Click not firing regularly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a custom slider animated with css. Dimensions set by flexbox logic. From slider-containers parent. slider-container has overflow:hidden, .all-slides is 300% wide and gets moved with transform(translate), each slide is 100% wide.

All jQuery needs to do is get the [data-activate-slide] value and play around with some classes. But every 5-15 times you click a trigger it doesn't fire the event. And I do not know why!
When you rehover the element it works 95% of the time. In the 5% fail another rehover and click works 100% in my tests.

Strangely often it is not working on "initial" / "first-time"-hover of the pagination.

I use jQuery 3.0.0. Same behavior change with 2.x– 
I'm not willing (time doesn't allow) to rewrite the whole thing with a different approach. Neither do I want to use an external slider for that.

Here you can watch the live example:
http://rrg.kreativzirkel.de/dienstleistungen

```
var ClickOrTap = (Modernizr.touchevents) ? "tap" : "click";

$("[data-activate-slide]").on(ClickOrTap, function(e) {

    // often doesn't even get to here
    console.log("activate-slide clicked");

    var toIndex = $(this).attr("data-activate-slide");
    var $container = $(this).parents(".slider-container");
    var $slides = $(".all-slides", $container);
    var $pagination = $(".pagination", $container);

    $slides.removeClass("slide-active-1 slide-active-2 slide-active-3");
    $slides.addClass("slide-active-" + toIndex);

    $pagination.children("div").removeClass("active").eq(toIndex - 1).addClass("active"); // active richtig setzen       
})
```

```
<div class="slider-container">
    <div class="all-slides">
        <div class="slide">...</div>
        <div class="slide">...</div>
        <div class="slide">...</div>
        <div class="slide">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="pagination">
        <div class="active" data-activate-slide="1">1</div>
        <div data-activate-slide="2">2</div>
        <div data-activate-slide="3">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.slider-container {

    overflow:hidden;

    .all-slides {

        width: 300%;
        .flexbox(row, flex-start, center);

        .slide { 
            width: 100%;
        }

        .transition(all 200ms ease-in-out);
        &.slide-active-1 { .translate(0); }
        &.slide-active-2 { .translate(calc(-100% * 1/3)); }
        &.slide-active-3 { .translate(calc(-100% * 2/3)); }

    }
}
```

Comment: Cant open your example. Please post a codepen or jsbin.

Comment: Oh, you're fast :D; Should work now– I had to reupload and remove the password protection.

Comment: Thx, i am not experiencing your problem, tried to click multiple times on overything and its working for me.

Comment: Fascinating. The problem does not seem to occur in Firefox that often, but it does. But in Safari it does very regularly. And on mobile Chrome it did as well. Two colleagues reported the same thing (mobile safari)